# Get the page count for printing in Objective-C Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, printing

ALL,

Is there a simple way to query printer from Cocoa to get a number of pages that will be printed with default settings, so that I can present this to the user in the printing panel?

Apple documentation has [this page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiprintformatter/1621843-pagecount?language=objc), but it says that it is available in `iOS` and `Mac Catalyst 13.0+`.

I need something to be useful in a regular Cocoa application starting with 10.9+.

Comment: Hey. It's iOS 4.2+ and Mac Catalyst 13.0+(which is iPad app running on Mac).

Comment: Is the number of pages not visible in the default print panel?

Comment: @Willeke, I am trying to create a custom print dialog.

Comment: Has `printOperation.pageRange` a valid value?